# error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator’

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to check if an input phrase is a palindrome.
Compiled using Xcode on MacBook Pro works fine. Complied on zyBooks website returns an error.

**How can update my code to address this issue?**

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userInput, palindromeCheck, reversedInput;
    getline(cin, userInput);
    
    palindromeCheck = userInput;
    
    remove(palindromeCheck.begin(), palindromeCheck.end(), ' ');
    palindromeCheck.erase(palindromeCheck.size() - 3, palindromeCheck.size());
    
    int temp = 1;

    while (temp < palindromeCheck.size() + 1)
    {
        reversedInput += palindromeCheck.at(palindromeCheck.size() - temp);
        ++temp;
    }
    if (reversedInput == palindromeCheck)
    {
        cout << userInput << " is a palindrome";
    }
    else
    {
      cout << userInput << " is not a palindrome";
    }

    cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The full error code from zyBooks is as follows:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:33: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator’ {aka ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’} to ‘const char*’
   14 |     remove(palindromeCheck.begin(), palindromeCheck.end(), ' ');
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                 |
      |                                 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6493,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:178:32: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int remove(const char*)’
  178 | extern int remove (const char *__filename) __THROW;
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:20:17: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   20 |     while (temp < palindromeCheck.size() + 1)
      |            ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You're missing `#include <algorithm>` for the `remove(...)` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove()` function without including the `algorithm.h` library works to delete the existing files in the system. The function signature of this function looks like:

```
int remove(const char *_Filename)
```

In the other hand, after using `algorithm.h`, you could now use the `remove()` for iterators:

```
_FIter remove<_FIter, _Tp>(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp &__value)
```

The problem was that there was no overload for the function where it accepts `std::string` object `begin()` and `end()` as arguments.